# Is it possible to customize errors in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

Lets say I have schema:

```
const transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "ID": {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        maxlength:36,
        minlength:35,
    }
...
}
```

And if my client try to save a document with ID of length less than 34, mongoose will produce this error

```
{
  "errors": {
    "ID": {
      "message": "Path `ID` (`k2131381a2asaddaddsdsw12sa3`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (35).",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "minlength": 35,
        "type": "minlength",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` (`{VALUE}`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (35).",
        "path": "ID",
        "value": "k2131381a2asaddaddsdsw12sa3"
      },
      "kind": "minlength",
      "path": "ID",
      "value": "k2131381a2asaddaddsdsw12sa3",
      "$isValidatorError": true
    }
  },
  "_message": "transaction validation failed",
  "message": "transaction validation failed: ID: Path `ID` (`k2131381a2asaddaddsdsw12sa3`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (35).",
  "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Now in order to tell my client the exact cause of error (i.e. ID is shorter than expected) I have to do a lot of hard work and write various if else statements like this:

```
if(error && error.ID && error.ID.kind === 'minlength'){
   res.status(400).json({error:45});//error 45 refers to ID length errors. Client knows about it
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? Is there a clean way to tell mongoose to just give me an error with code 45 when ID length is inappropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `validate` object in the `Schema` definition.

In the `message` object in `validate` , you can specify any message of your choice

```
const transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "ID": {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        validate : {
            validator : (data)=>{
                if(data.length >=35 && data.length <=36 ){
                    return true; //validation success
                }
                else{
                    return false; // validation failure
                }
            },
            message : "Length mismatch. Length must be >=35 and <=36"
        }
    }
...
}
```

Lets assume that you have to insert a record into this schema, you can make use of `validateSync()` method to trigger validation specified in the schema before doing the `insert` operation.

```
var transaction = new transaction({ID : "myid"});
var validationResult = transaction.validateSync();
if(validationResult == null){
    //validation success
    //proceed with insert operation
}
else{
    //validation failure
    //you can extract all the key fields that failed the validation using errors object in validationResult object

    for (x in validationResult.errors) {
        // print error messages of specific field
        console.log(validationResult.errors[x].message);
    }
}
```

You can print the `validationResult`  object to see what the `validationResult` object has.

The most useful object for us will be the `validationResult.errors` object as shown in the above code